# Asp.net core identity: check if user is admin in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core 2.1 identity project set up with a seeded role "admin", and a seeded user "admin". According to my database, the user admin has the role admin, but when I do:

```
@User.IsInRole("admin")
```

I get false regardless if I'm logged in or not
I've tried to search for an answer, and I've found the following

```
@Roles.IsUserInRole(User.UserName, "admin")
```

and

```
@User.HasClaim("role", "admin")
```

For the first one, "Roles" doesn't seem to be defined, and the second one didn't work.
What am I doing wrong? Did I forget something?

Comment: To use `@User.IsInRole("admin")` you need a role `"admin"` in your `Roles` table and the current users needs to be mapped to that role in `UserRoles` table

Comment: I do, like I said, I checked the database, the role exists, and the user is added to it

Comment: Why aren't you using the [UserManager.IsInRoleAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.isinroleasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_UserManager_1_IsInRoleAsync__0_System_String_) Method by Identity? It lets you check if a user is in a specific role.

Comment: I think I checked that too, but I can't remember, gonna check it tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue in the version of 2.1 and has been fixed in 2.2 preview-1 .

In asp.net core 2.1, `AddDefaultIdentity` is used and the injection becomes to

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
```

,will not make Roles enabled by default and it always return false for User.IsInRole.

To walk around it , instead of using the new `AddDefaultIdentity<TUser>()` to configure Identity , simply use the old-style api :

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813

Comment: I switched to policies and claims, but thanks very much +1

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research, and it seems like it's more advisable to create policies and use those instead of roles. So I need to modify my code a bit.